# Assign variable in mathematica

Tags: variables, wolfram-mathematica

Can I ask for some help in the assigning of variables in my matematica module to solve for my PD function.

```
 PD[a_,l_]:= Module[(a=[x1,y1,P],l=[x2,y2]; PD.=P./(4*pi*((x2-x1)^2)+(y2-y1)^2))]
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. There is a website http://Mathematica.StackExchange.com, I'm suggesting that is a better place for your question. A moderator should be able to migrate it for you.

Comment: If I understand what you mean (the syntax is incorrect) the inputs to `PD` are `x1, y1, x2, y2, P` rather than `a, l`.

Comment: Here's some unasked for help: `PD.=` does not have a syntactically-correct form, nor does `P./`; don't expect the variable `pi` to be interpreted to have the value `3.14159...`; finally, it's unusual in Mathematica to make an assignment in a function to a variable with the same name as the function, a Module will return a value or values if you write it properly.

Comment: Thanks B.gatessucks !! I am confused in the assigning of variables. the argument 'a' is made up of my  list of {x1,y1,P} and 'l' is made up of {x2,y2} these elements  are components of my final equation which I have edited to be   N[PD=(P/(4*Pi*((x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1))))  ]] - My question is how do I assign the elements of the list to their specific arguments. My in function would have values for each of the elements listed as such PD[{x1,y1,P},{x2,y2}]

Answer (score 1):

Something like :

```
pd[a_, l_] :=  a[[3]]/(4 Pi ((l[[1]] - a[[1]])^2 + (l[[2]] - a[[2]])^2))

pd[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}]
(* 1/(24 \[Pi]) *)
```

You might also want to redefine your arguments; for instance :

```
pd2[r1_, r2_, p_] = p/(4 Pi EuclideanDistance[r1, r2]^2);

pd2[{1, 2}, {4, 5}, 3]
(* 1/(24 \[Pi]) *)
```